# Webbrowser - update second dropdown list after choosing an item from the first dropdown list

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control

My goal is to update second dropdown list which is updated after choosing an item from the first dropdown list. Any help would be appreciated.
I can't detect when start ajax activity in webbrowser control. I've tried instructions in this thread with no success, implemented the following class:
HTML:

```
<html>
<Head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://myweb.com/scripts/jquery_1.5.js">
</head>
<body>
<select id =”cboCity”>
<option value=”1”> C1 </option>
<option value=”2”> C2 </option>
<option value=”3”> C3 </option>
<select id =”cboDistrict”>
<option value=”1”> D1 </option>
<option value=”2”> D2 </option>
<option value=”3”> D3 </option>
</body>
</html>
```

C# Code:

```
System.Windows.Forms.Timer timer1;
HtmlElement city = webbrowser1.doc.GetElementById("cboCity ");
      city.Focus();
      city.SetAttribute("value", "2");
      city.InvokeMember("onchange");

      timer1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
      timer1.Tick +=new EventHandler(timer1_Tick);
      timer1.Interval = 1000;
      timer1.Enabled = true;
      timer1.Start();

private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      HtmlElement district = webbrowser1.doc.GetElementById("cboDistrict");
      district.Focus();
      district.SetAttribute("value", "3");
      district.InvokeMember("onchange");

      timer1.Stop();
      this.timer1.Enabled = false;
    }
```

Comment: Did you ever manage to solve this?

Comment: hi have you solved this? I have the same issue

Answer (score 1):

You can use jquery to do that.

```
$(function() {
    $("#cboCity").change(function() {
        var currentSelection = $(this).val();
//grab the other items
//loop trough them
//inert into $("cboDistrict").html();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use jQuery and the change even on the dropdown?
http://api.jquery.com/change/